# Equi-convergence of a function family at a point?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, measure-theory

The definition of [uniform integrability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_integrable) of a family of $L^1$ functions is:

> If μ is a finite measure, a subset $K \subset L^1(\mu) $ is said to be
>   uniformly integrable if  $\lim_{c \to \infty} \sup_{X \in K}
>  \int_{|X|\geq c} |X|\, d\mu = 0.$

It inspires the following attempt to coordinate convergence of each in a function family as approaching a domain limit point:

1. Suppose $\{f_a\}_{a \in A}$ is a family of functions from $U \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $x_0$ is a limit point of $U$ in $\mathbb{R}$, and $L \in \mathbb{R}$. Are there some existing concepts for cases similar to the
   one when  $\lim_{x\to x_0} \sup_{a \in A} |f_a(x) -L| = 0$?
2. Can such concepts be generalized for a family of mappings defined
   from a subset of a topological space to a metric space? By replacing absolute value with metric, I think the example in 1 can. Can the codomains be  generalized to a uniform space or even a topological space?
3. Would it be called "equi-convergence", or "uniform convergence" (bad name as it is already used for another purpose) in the same spirit of "uniform integrability"? This is because I notice the difference between the naming of   "equi"-continuity of a family of mappings at a domain point, and the naming of "uniform" continuity of a mapping over its domain ("uniform" seems always suggest the existence of a uniform space).

   In the same spirit, do you think "uniform integrability" is really a bad
   name, and probably "equi-integrability" will be a better one?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: That title is nigh-unparsable!

Comment: I guess for question 1 you have to look at the notion of equi-continuity, but it's already what you are doing in another question. The concept of uniform integrability can be extended to function with values into a Banach space. For question 3, you can see that a function is integrable if an only if $\lim_{c\to \infty}\int_{|X|\geq c}|X|d\mu=0$, and when you have a family of random variables this limit is uniform, so it's not a so bad name.

Comment: @Tim: I mean that your title has extremely convoluted grammar. It's in passive voice (always more difficult to parse than active voice), the direct object is "each in a function family" ("function family" is also bad); and the indirect object is a participle. Why not try for direct active voice and stop trying to make it sound erudite? "Defining convergence of a family of functions at a point" or "Defining coordinated convergence for a family of functions at a point"?

Comment: @Tim: **Much** better...

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: Thanks! "when you have a family of random variables this limit is uniform", but this "uniform" is over the family of random variables, not over their domain. So I would think "equi" will be better, as it is over a family of mappings, such as in equicontinuity.